# Set fetched record default value for using in Blade

Tags: laravel, model, laravel-blade, laravel-5.4

I trying to fetch all users fields from database with this method:

```
$user = Users::all();
```

I have some fields in my database which is `nullable` I want to know is there any way to set a default value for null fields when use in blade ?

For example I have this fields:

```
first_name, last_name, bio, city, fb_account, twitter_account , ...
```

All of this fields are optional (an nullable in database) I want show `N/A` for fields with null value but I don't want use `@if` for each field,

is it possible ?

**UPDATE :**

I want use `{{ $user->first_name }}` everywhere and if this was `null` return `N/A and if`not null` return himself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the user object using the [each](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-each) method before sending it to the view

```
$user = Users::all()->each(function ($item, $key) {
    if ($item->first_name === null) {
        $item->first_name = 'N/A';
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, `each()` not work for `find()`, what should I do if I use `find()` instead of `all()`

Comment: `find()` would return an model instance instead of a collection, you could try performing a `foreach` loop on the instance or try calling the find method with an array of primary keys, which will return a collection of the matching records like `find([1])`

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in Laravel 5.4

```
{{ $first_name or 'N/A' }}
```

It is exactly the same as

```
echo isset($first_name) ? $first_name : 'N/A';
```

Based on your update, you can look into [Accessor & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

You can then something like this:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    if(! empty($value)) 
    {
      return $value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no any way to set default value ? because I want use `{{ $user->first_name }}` everywhere and if this is `null` return `N/A` and if not null return himself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that, you can use custom attributes

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->first_name ?: 'N/A';
}
```

and then

```
{{ $item->first_name }}
```